# is it possible, that for loop iterates by time in nodejs

Tags: node.js, loops, for-loop, time

```
let orders = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., 100];
let drivers = [1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 50];

for (let order of orders) {
  for (let driver of drivers) {
    // run 2nd iteration after 30 sec or one mint
  }
}
```

I have a list of orders and drivers, I want to assign one order to one driver. if the driver rejects the order(g.e: Id=1) same order goes to the next driver after 30 sec or 0ne mint.
please guide me.
I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968289/javascript-run-loop-for-specified-time/14968331) but not working correctly in my case.

Comment: I don't think `for` loop (or any other loop) is a good choice for this kind of work. You need something more sophisticated, like streams, or event emitters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Generally, it is not a good design choice to block the thread for a given amount of time, but the OP seems to be sufficient, so I'm just going to try and answer it without going into the "best practice" territory.*

You need to put this double loop in an `async` function and delay the flow for a given amount of time using another async function:

```js
const delay = (msec) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, msec));

let orders = [1,2,3,4,5,......100];
let drivers = [1,2,3,4,....50];

(async function main() {
  for (let order of orders) {
    for (let driver of drivers) {
      // (pseudocode) suggest the order to the driver
      driver.suggestOrder(order);

      // wait for half a minute
      await delay(30_000);

      // (pseudocode) don't suggest the same order to another driver
      if (driver.agreedToOrder(order)) break;
    }
  }
})();
```